# Frequency of characters on string pointers array

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am working on an exercise which asks me to:

1. read 20 words from the user,
2. save them on pointers array depending on their size with memory,
   allocation.
3. find the frequency of the letters,
4. print them out on histogram.

Step 1 and 2 work fine on my code. The problem is on the frequency. I have placed a testing `printf` to see if it's working and it comes out that it doesn't count the chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N         20
#define MAX_SIZE  200

int main() {
    char *words[N];
    int i, c = 0, length;
    char *temp;
    int freq[26] = { 0 };

    temp = (char *)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Give a word:");
        gets(temp);
        length = strlen(temp);
        *(words + i) = (char *)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(*(words + i), temp);
        printf("%s\n", *(words + i));
    }
    free(temp);

    while (*words[c] != '\0' && c < 20) {
        if ((*words[c] >= 'a' && *words[c] <= 'z') || (*words[c] >= 'A' &&  *words[c] <= 'Z')) {                    
            freq[*words[c] - 'a']++;
            words[c]++;
        }
        c++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", i + 'a', freq[c]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indenting your code will help others reading it and understanding what your problem is.

Comment: Also, you don't distinguish between uppercase and lowercase when you're increasing the frequence. 'b'-'a' is different from 'B'-'a', and will give you issues

Comment: You *do* know that `*(words + i)` is equivalent to `words[i]`? And while both can be used pretty much interchangeably, the latter is usually preferred as it really shows what you're doing (indexing an array). Also, `sizeof(char)` always results in the value `1`, as per the C specification.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 you are correct i will take care of it,  can you explain more your 2st comment?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yea i know its the same

Comment: I also need to point that im bigginer so dont be harsh

Comment: @user2719403 Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- you modify the pointers in the `words` array instead of iterating via an index.
- you check for upper case letters but access offsets outside of its boundaries with `freq[*words[c]-'a']` in this case.
- there is a typo in the last loop: it should be `freq[i]` instead if `freq[c]`.
- you do not need to allocate the array `temp`.
- you must not use `gets` that was removed from the standard. `gets` cannot check for buffer overflow, any malicious input can have untold consequences.
- you should check for `malloc` failure

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N         20
#define MAX_SIZE  200

int main(void) {
    char *words[N];
    int n, i, j, c, length;
    char temp[MAX_SIZE];
    int freq[26] = { 0 };

    for (n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        printf("Give a word:");
        if (!fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin))
            break;
        temp[strcspn(temp, "\n")] = '\0';  /* strip the \n if present */
        length = strlen(temp);
        words[n] = malloc(length + 1);
        if (words[n] == NULL) {
            printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(words[n], temp);
        printf("%s\n", words[n]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; (c = words[i][j]) != '\0'; j++) {
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                freq[c - 'a']++;
            else
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                freq[c - 'A']++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (freq[i] > 0)
            printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered strings.\n", i + 'a', freq[c]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD ! you are correct. It solves part of the problem, for example if i put;

Comment: if i put 'ab' at input , it will only count the 'a' and not the 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to only check the first letter of each word, then move on to the next word. clearly you need 2 loops working there.

or something like:

```
while (c<N) {
    if(( *words[c]>='a' && *words[c]<='z') || (*words[c]>='A' &&  *words[c]  <='Z')) {                    

        freq[*words[c]-'a']++;
    }
    words[c]++;
    if(*words[c] == '\0')
        c++;
}
```

but i think you will end up with an array of ends of strings, it dos not seem to matter, but it is still strange.

Comment: I Found the solution i think.. in your above code if you change the != with == it will work.. cause it will go to next word when there is no more chars to read..

Comment: oh, sorry for giving a buggy solution ^^. glade it helped.

Comment: No problem , Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

Start by distinguishing between upper and lower case. This may not be the complete solution, but it's a start.

```
    if (*words[c]>='a' && *words[c]<='z'){                       
        freq[*words[c]-'a']++;
        words[c]++;
    }
    else if (*words[c]>='A' &&  *words[c]  <='Z'){                       
        freq[*words[c]-'A']++;
        words[c]++;
    }
```

Comment: Understood , i do it imidiatelly

Comment: Wouldn't #include <ctype.h> and use islower(), isupper() simpler?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 i did it , now sometimes it gives me that all letters have been shown 1 time , and other times it gives me all 0.

Comment: @user2719403 Check chqrlie's answer. His answer fixes that bug

Comment: @BlueMoon93 partly fixes the problem